# Python making a schedule calendar

Tags: python-3.x, calendar, text-files, schedule, file-writing

is there anyway in Python to write a program that writes a text-file with the days schedule? If you are running, and sleeping in: 01/11/2020, I want the textfile to write:

01/11/2020

running

sleeping

But then If the user says another date I want the textfile to write the information from the other date, etc.

Comment: Can you please explain the question you have. Its bit unclear

Comment: Say that you have a list of different activities for one season. For example between 2020-11-21 - 2021-01-01 your activities are a = [running, sleeping]. You want to ask the user of what date he/she want to pick. If the user pick between the dates 2020-11-21 - 2021-01-01 I want a textfile to be written for the activities on that date

Comment: @AmilaMGunawardana

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi Lets say that you have a multidimensional array of data you can use below method to access each elements.

eg:

```py
    l = numpy.array([["2020-01-10",20],["2020-01-12",30]])
    for i in l:
       if i[0] = "2020-01-10":
           with open("Output.txt", "w") as text_file:
              text_file.write("Value %s" % i[1])
```

**Or try using pandas**
Get all the data to pandas data frame and query like below

```py
data = (df['date'] > '2000-6-1') & (df['date'] <= '2000-6-10')
print(df.loc[data])
```

Comment: Thank you sir! Just one question if I want the textfile to write out every activity for a year and specifically for each day is it possible? For example I have a list for specific one season say between  2020-11-21 - 2021-01-01 and another for 2021-01-02 - 2021-03-31. I want the textfile to be able to write out the activities for each  day like: 2020-11-21: running, sleeping, 2020-11-22: running, sleeping... until 2021-01-02: eating, sleeping, 2021-01-03: eating, sleeping etc...

Comment: yes you can use multiple filters to same pandas data frame. Or in the first approach use multiple if conditions.

Comment: I see do you have a example of how?

Comment: You mean like: 
data = (df['date'] > '2000-6-1') & (df['date'] <= '2000-6-10')
print(df.loc[data]). What is df?

Comment: It’s the pandas dataframe. you can use multiple filter conditions like this.